# Getting Error CS0272 The property or indexer cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible

Tags: c#, .net

After signing an assembly class and exposing the internals to a friend assembly with the InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssembly,PublicKey=   ") attribute, I am getting a 'Set accessor is inaccessible error'. The property is:

```
public datatype PropertyName { get; internal set; }
```

I don't want to change the access modifier of the Set accessor.

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `[InternalsVisibleTo]`?

Comment: Did you compile the C# from the command line? If so, you must use the /out compiler switch to ensure that the name of the friend assembly is available when the compiler binds to external references.

Comment: @pmf In Assemblyinfo.cs of other project

Comment: @swatsonpicken No

Comment: Are both your assembly and the friend assembly signed? I wonder if exposing the internals "in an unsigned way" without using the PublicKey part of the attribute, i.e. [InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssembly")] will work in this case?

Comment: @swatsonpicken I think it works, even though you are not supposed to do this.

Comment: Which "other project"? The `[InternalsVisibleTo]` must be in the project that contains the definitions which are internal. So this must be in the same assembly your property with the internal setter is.

Comment: @swatsonpicken No Sir Didn't sign the friend assembly,  Since I am Signing assembly according to Build Order

Comment: @Sudesh Ah, ok. In that case check out the full answer I wrote below. Seeing as the friend assembly is not signed you need to use the shorter version of InternalsVisibleTo which does not include the PublicKey part.

Comment: @PMF yes it is in the same assembly where internal setter is

Comment: A [mcve] would make it much easier to understand what you've actually done. We shouldn't need to ask this many questions in order to understand the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for Suggestion, Will keep In mind Next time .

Comment: Why wait until next time? You can still edit *this* question to make it clear what situation you were facing, at which point the question and answer will be more useful to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo...)]` attribute must be in the assembly that contains the internal properties you wish to expose.

If your assembly is strong name signed, then the friend assembly must also be strong name signed and you must use:

`[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssembly, PublicKey=...)]`

Where the PublicKey part is the full public key from the strong-named key file of the friend assembly.

If your assembly is **not** signed then use:

`[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssembly")]`

Comment: if I remove a PublicKey form Unsigned Friend Assembly Getting Error CS1726 Friend assembly reference  is invalid. Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations.

Comment: @Sudesh From my reading of the Microsoft documentation, a strong name signed assembly can only grant friend assembly access to other strongly signed assemblies. For this reason you must either sign the friend assembly if you can or remove the strong name signing from your own assembly.

Comment: Thank You! After signing Both Assembly my Assembly and Friend Assembly Error get Resolved